# A space train falls front first into a black hole

Tags: black-holes, tidal-effect

A long space train's HAL 2000 computer goes wacko and drives the ship and its sleeping crew front first straight into a Black Hole. As it nears/crosses the event horizon, does the space train break up due to gravitational stretching from the rear first, the front first, or evenly ?

Contrary to depictions on YouTube which suggest the closest parts break up first, my quick calculations put the rear under most stress due to huge momentum forces from it being accelerated forward in its weaker gravitational field by the front of the train, as opposed to the front which is in free fall except for being held back by the rest of the space train's increasing momentum.

Think of a merry go round which simulates the increasing gravitational field. A long heavy rubber Bungy stretches more at the centre of the MGR  where it is tethered than at the loose end because the tethered end carries the full weight of the Bungy. If it goes around fast enough the Bungy will break off at the tether not at the loose end or in the middle. Am I correct?

POSTEDIT:

Thank you both for your very considered replies. I've come up with a modified view based on both replies.

It is natural to assume that:

the train is falling freely.

But if you think about it more closely, only the Centre of Gravity is in free fall (by definition). The CoG will also move toward the front (singularity end) as it increasingly accelerates toward the BH. Thus the front will become increasingly more massive than the rear but balancing this is that the CoG (of the falling train system) will be closer to the front. The momentum of the increasingly but relatively less massive rear will be effectively holding back the front.

A passenger on the train at the CoG will be in free fall but as the CoG moves forward, the passenger experiences an increasing differential gravity away from the CoG either side of it. This differential gravity is the expansive force acting on the train to break it up. Therefore, I suggest, the system is like a merry-go-round except that the bungy is initially tethered just off its centre to the centre of the MGR, but starts gradually slipping further from its tether (due to the extra pull of the longer "half") as it spins faster.

The longer "half" of the bungy represents the part of the space train furthest from the BH and is subject to the greatest stretching forces, but these forces are propagated back additively to the CoG.

Consequently, in both cases the break up starts at the CoG, which is where strain first begins to exceed the tensile strength of the materials, and the pattern repeats fractal like for each of the subsequent parts, and well before any Space warping due to extreme gravity comes into play.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Oooo, multiple choice. I vote for front since that is where the strain will exceed the tensile strength of the materials.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between your bungee cord analogy and the train is that the bungee cord is secured to the centre of the merry go round while the train is falling freely. So unlike the bungee, the far end of the train is not supporting the weight of the parts of the train nearer the singularity.

The tidal acceleration between two points separated by a small distance $\ell$ at a radius $r$  from the singularity is:

$$ a_t = c^2 \ell \frac{r_s}{r^3} $$

where $r_s$ is the radius of the event horizon. The tidal acceleration is greatest for smallest $r$, so the train will indeed start to come apart nearest the singularity.